# Regex - Match last occurrence of parentheses

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching, regex-lookarounds, regexp-replace

In the below string I am trying to get the substring `(2005, Penguin Classics)` substring.

> Marshall B. Rosenberg PhD - The Surprising Purpose of Anger_ Beyond
> Anger Management_ Finding the Gift (Nonviolent Communication Guides)
> (2005, Penguin Classics) AAA.pdf

I am doing this to change the substring to just (2005).

Below is my current solution but it matches both `(Nonviolent Communication Guides)` and `(2005, Penguin Classics)`. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
import re

parentheses_pattern = "\(([^)]+)\)*$"
reg = re.search(parentheses_pattern, filename)
year = reg.group()
year = year[:5]+")"
filename = re.sub(parentheses_pattern,year,filename)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work maybe?

```
\(\d+, .*\)
```

A good place to test your regex is this: https://rubular.com/

Just in case it comes in handy! :)

Comment: Thanks! Wouldn't this fail if the first substring has leading digits though?

Comment: It wouldn't because of the comma and the space in the Regex. So even if it is: [...](23 Nonviolent Communication Guides) (2005, Penguin Classics)[...] it will still choose the substring you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will help:

```
r"\(([^\)]+)\)[^\(]*$"
```

Comment: Thanks! What is the use of the r character at the start?

Comment: By the way it is not working as it truncates the file extension (.pdf) at the end

Comment: I thought the objective was to match the content in the last occurrence of parentheses - which is what the pattern does. In any case, you can try `r"\(([^\)]+)\)(?=[^\(]*$)"` instead.